# What does watch chain mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was watching an English educational program on TV and I heard the word: watch chain. A tailor said he often wears watch chain. I tried to look after and search for this phrase but I couldn’t find the answer. It’s not clear for me that if someone uses the phrase ‘watch chain’ does it refer to only the chain or is the pocket watch included?

Comment: Where did you search? A basic image search for "watch chain" turns up pictures of watch chains. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/watch%20chain) has an entry for "watch chain"

Comment: Yes, I did an image search on Google but sometimes it showed only the chain, sometimes a chain with a watch. That’s why I couldn’t decide, that watch chain refers to only for the chain or chain with a watch. It’s not clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

The tailor likely said "I often wear **a** watch chain."

It refers to a chain that connects a hand-held watch to someone's clothes. It was common a long time ago to have these watches and wear them with chains. And although those watches are no longer common, people wear the chains sometimes as a style choice.

See [images of watch chains](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=watch+chain&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover)

Comment: Why a downvote?